# Does using django querysets in templates hit the database?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-queryset

Do template value tags force django to hit the database when called against a non-context value?

For example:

`{{ request.user.username }}` Is the call to show the currently logged in user's username.  However, something like `{{ request.user.someobject_set.all }}` will dump a FK traversed queryset into the template.

Does the user's `someobject` set get dumped into context by default, or do I need to make a context entry with a queryset in the `def get_context_data` of my view?  And by extension, any other, non-request object that may be found by association?

The below doc shows when the querysets are evaluated in raw python, but doesn't really mention templates and views and their relationship.

---

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Evaluating things in the template is exactly the same as evaluating them anywhere else. When the template is rendered, the variables will be resolved, and if the object referred to requires a database lookup, then one will be carried out by that object. But this isn't the template doing anything clever, it's just telling `request.user` to fetch its `someobject_set` attribute and then calling `all` on it which is exactly the same as would happen in Python code.

Comment: So for clarity, to save on db hits, I should be putting any items I might need into the context before rendering.  Would that be a safe statement?

Comment: Well, not really. It depends on what else you're doing with that data. If you need it elsewhere, then sure: get it once in the view and pass it in to avoid duplicate lookups. But if that's the only time you need it, then there's no reason to avoid triggering the db hit in the template.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  Just as an additional tidbit: It seems django is exceptional at knowing what to cache for the remainder of the session. I was doing to playing with django-debug-toolbar and found that once I get a set of just about anything, it doesn't hit the db again for that request.