# Should Django Querysets Be Called in the Templates or Passed Into The Template Context?

Tags: django, django-templates

I may get blowback from asking this question but it's something I've wondered about for a while so here goes.

In a Django template, you *can* use `.all` to get the queryset of things, like so:

```
{% for prerequisite in object.prerequisites.all %}
  <li class="list-group-item">{{ prerequisite.text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

The model in this case looks like this, but the only relevant piece of information is that `object` above has a relation to the `Prerequisite` model through the ForeignKey.

```
class Prerequisite(models.Model):
    content = models.ForeignKey(Content, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='prerequisites')
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.text)
```

**My question is**

Is it best-practice to call Django querysets in the template, (ie: `object.prerequisites.all`) or should one pass it in the view through the context?

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['prerequisites'] = self.object.prerequisites.all()
    return context
```

It's really convenient to do querysets in the template, but it seems like it should be business logic located in the view. Does Django have a specific stance on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does using django querysets in templates hit the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23787767/does-using-django-querysets-in-templates-hit-the-database)

Comment: @MohitC Thanks. That does provide one elite Django user's perspective. I can't say it answers the question. I admit, this question is a bit "opinion-based", which is why I hesitated to ask it, but hopefully other Django powerusers will chime in and provide their opinion.

Answer (score 1):

according to django documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/#the-view-layer

> The view layer -
> Django has the concept of “views” to encapsulate the logic responsible for processing a user’s request and for returning the response.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/#the-template-layer

> The template layer -
> The template layer provides a designer-friendly syntax for rendering the information to be presented to the user.

i have different example, i know a lot of programmers loves to move buisness logic from `views.py` to `serializer.py`, even if original purpose of serialezers life is  - `to serialize`

i believe the most appropriate way is to `pass your data through context` in the views.

Views originally is all your buisness logic, serializer suppose only serialization, and templates purpose is to show html page, python wasn't originaly desined to manipulate html page